# Swapping active record objects that are sorted by attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `CheckIn` model with a `:week` field.  I normally sort these record by `:week`

```
CheckIn.all.order(:week)
```

I also give a user the ability to re-order these records, which effectively updated the `:week` attribute, resulting in a new order.  The problem is that when I update the `:week`, there is already another record with that `:week` number.

In other words if I start with this:

```
ci1 = CheckIn.create(week: 0)
ci2 = CheckIn.create(week: 1)
ci3 = CheckIn.create(week: 2)
ci4 = CheckIn.create(week: 3)
```

then update the `week` of `ci2` to 2:

```
ci2.update({ week: 2})
```

I am left with an array of `check_ins` but 2 records have the same week number, when ideally the old 2 would become 1.  Is there something built into rails to help this situation or would I need a callback to update the week numbers?

Comment: looks like you want week column to be unique, what you can do is add a before_save filter and swap the values for week if you are updating existing week checkin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of gems that'll help you with record ordering in this manner. They'll automatically push the subsequent records "down" when inserting mid-list. Check out [`acts_as_list`](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) or [`ranked-model`](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model).